# every page it's own id in CSS file

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working on a website and finished the frontpage which is index.html and customized its css into one file to be used as a template by all pages coming.

Now I have a problem.

How do I get all pages to display their own background images?

option1   let the background.img be added to the html of its own page .. (1.img in 1.html instead of
inside the CSS file)

option2   give every page its own id (somehow) inside the css file.

option3  another solution.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image: url(index.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;


}
.topParagraph{
                
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.topbar{

    text-align: right;
    
}

.content{
    background:whitesmoke;
    
    width: 50%;
    padding:10%;
    margin:200px auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    opacity: 0,5;
}
{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body
{

    background-image: url(deKlomp.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}
.menu-bar
{

    background: #0b2463;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-bar ul
{
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color:#fff
    
}
.menu-bar ul li
{
    widows: 120px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 12px;


}
.menu-bar ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;

}
.active, .menu-bar ul li:hover
{
    background: #66c2ff;
    border-radius:3px;

}
.menu-bar .fa
{
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.sub-menu-1
{
    display:none;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background:  #66c2ff;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;

}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul
{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;

}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li
{
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: left;


}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;

}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li a:hover
{
    color:  #66c2ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change `.body` class, you have to use different CSS files for specific HTML files. Instead, take another CSS `class` and html `<div>`, then assign `background-image: url(index.jpg);` to it.

Comment: Thanks.. It is not that I revuze to change the .body class.. I just did not knew how nd in wich way.

Comment: I will try out your sugestion. I will leave a last comment when it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was remving the body class from the CSS file and add it individually to the html pages. In there I changed the picture.img file to the one I wanted. Each page its own!

This worked out perfectly.